# Bluetooth Low energy simple code, error on discover()

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to run the next code with `python3 ble.py`:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import discover

async def run():
    devices = await discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(d)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

to see how many available devices there are, but I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ble.py", line 10, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(run())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "ble.py", line 5, in run
    devices = await discover()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bleak/backends/bluezdbus/discovery.py", line 173, in discover
    ).asFuture(loop)
txdbus.error.RemoteError: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.21" (uid=1000 pid=1170 comm="python3 ble.py ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (uid=0 pid=442 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
```

I don't understand the meaning of the error, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you running your code as root, e.g. using sudo?

Comment: Yes, but it didnt solve the issue. Adding the user to the bluetooth group did (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem, adding the user to the bluetooth group solved the issue.